# Cycling through colors and defining a color map matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm looping through a list of list of file paths where I want a separate figure for each sublist. In each sublist I open the file as a dataframe, plot y1 and y2 (which I want in the same color), and then move to the next file/dataframe in that list where I want both lines to be a different color to the first.

My question is how do I define the colormap I want to use? The following does not seem to have any impact on the output of my plots regardless what cmap i choose to use:

```
for x in configurations:                          # configurations is a list of list of directories
    plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'Accent'         # Not working
    prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
    colors = prop_cycle.by_key()['color']
    for i, y in enumerate(x):        
        df = pd.read_fwf(y, header=None, comment='#', skiprows=53, skip_empty_rows=True)           
        df['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch'])
        line1 = plt.plot(df['epoch'],df['y1'], color=colors[i])
        line2 = plt.plot(df['epoch'],df['y2'], color=colors[i])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']` evaluates to a `cycler` object that,
by itself, is not particularly useful but you can *call* the `cycler`
to get an `itertools.cycle` object that can be passed to `next` to
have a dictionary that you have to unpack (the `**` operator) in the
arguments list of the plotting command

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np                                                                                     

configurations = [ ['f0', 'f1', 'f2'], ['g0', 'g1']]                                                   

def get_df(fname):
# I have no Pandas, this fakes a data set
    global n 
    n += 0.2 
    return dict(x=[0,1,2,3,4,5], 
                y1=[0,2+n,3+n,3+n,2+n,0], 
                y2=[3+n,2+n,0,-2-n,-3-n, -3-n])                                                        

n = 0 
for conf in configurations: 
    prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']() 
    fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True) 
    ax = fig.add_subplot() 
    for fname in conf: 
        curr_dict = next(prop_cycle) 
        df = get_df(fname) 
        ax.plot('x', 'y1', '', data=df, label='y1 from '+fname, **curr_dict) 
        ax.plot('x', 'y2', '', data=df, label='y2 from '+fname, **curr_dict, linestyle='--') 
    ax.legend() 
    fig.savefig(fname[0]+'.png')
```

the above resets the cycle each time you enter a new figure, I expect
this is reasonable… otherwise place the statement `prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']()` outside of the loops.

[image]
[image]